# Can anyone tell me how to give to lists as arguments to a function in Haskell? (type declaration)

Tags: list, function, haskell

I want to write a function that gets two lists and fuses them to one list but in the reverse order so [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] become [4,5,6,1,2,3] and well I am kind of stuck at the type declaration ...

Comment: Also, stackoverflow told me to not post that comment and just downvote instead. Real nice, SO.

Comment: yeah thanks, downvoting is the solution... *****

Comment: have tried [a] [a] -> [a] and some other stuff that was impossible to

Comment: It's `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: But why didn`t this work? (I tried this already...) When I continued with the code I wrote listreverse [] [] = [] and there was a type error... like expected type [[a]] but...

Comment: "There was a type error" doesn't tell us much. Show your code and the exact error you get if you want help.

Comment: Well, sorry if it feels bad to get downvoted as a newbie, but the way you've posted this question just isn't fine. StackOverflow expects some demonstrated effort at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: It does not "feel bad". It just is not of any help. I ignore questions if I do not like them and dont downvote a new question, that has no answers yet...

Comment: I have found another mistake. Program is running now with [a] -> [a] -> [a] so thanks!

Comment: "It just is not of any help" -- The primary goal of downvoting is not to help the asker, but to improve the content of the site by encouraging people to ask better questions and making downvoted questions available for further moderation mechanisms. That said, you may well find the feedback useful for preparing your future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's show you how I think about haskell
So let's think about the types first. You have a 2 lists of something and return a list of these thing. In the language of types this is looking like this: `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Once you know the type you can ask hoogle: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ which should give you everything you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

Your function has two parameters: `list1` and `list2`.
The result of your function is a list of the same type. This means that your function is dealing with three lists. Two of which are parameters, the third one is the result.

To keep it simple, let's say you're dealing with lists of `Integers`. The type declaration would look like this:

```
fuse :: [Int] -> -- The first list
        [Int] -> -- The second list
        [Int]    -- The result fusion
```

Where `[Int]` represents a list of `Integers`. Of course, the function doesn't have to be lists of `Integers`. It could be applied to lists that contain elements of any type:

```
fuse :: [a] -> -- The first list
        [a] -> -- The second list
        [a]    -- The result of the fusion
```

A quick search on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)  for `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` will give you the `(++)` function as the top result:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

This function appends two lists. In your case, you could use the function like this:

```
fuse :: [a] -> -- The first list
        [a] -> -- The second list
        [a]    -- The result
fuse list1 list2 = list2 ++ list1
```

Or in point-free style:

```
fuse :: [Int] -> -- The first list
        [Int] -> -- The second list
        [Int]    -- The result
fuse = flip (++)
```

The flip function reverses the arguments.